# overflox-x not showing but i can scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css

i felt weirded out, i had a container with a margin auto, but why is it that i can  scroll horizontally? i cannot see overflow-x scroll though.

[image]

i also tried:

```
body, html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but this is the result, equal margin but not centered? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To center your div, you can try :

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -260px; /* div width / 2 */
```

Comment: You shouldn't use absolute pixel values or negative margins to center an element, especially with responsive design or other dynamic elements. A better bet is to use `margin: 0 auto;` on a block element or `text-align: center;` on an inline element's parent element or even the new "defacto center" using `position: relative` on the parent with `position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` on the child. Which of these will help OP it's impossible to tell without more code or a link to the site in question.